# how to alter ScrollView scrollTo scrolling speed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been working with `Scrollview` which contains a list view containing  page indicators as numbers. When I click on them, I want them to scroll so that the selected number is in the center

like

> 4 5 6 [7] 8 9

7 is selected number here ,
when I click on 9 here

the scrollview scrolls left so that view comes as

> 7 8 [9] 10 11

I'm using `scrollTo(x : calculated  , y : 0 , animated : true)`
however the scroll is too slow. I want the scroll to be fast or controllable by a parameter, I've tried duration in `scrollTo` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

This is currently not possible. A call of scrollTo results in a call of [scrollResponderScrollTo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/ad8a33586410c6f9048983f64f8f86e0715e73b8/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder.js#L372-L387), which then calls either the [ios implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/520ad05ba07a3442f88f070458c70db5d1c74cc9/React/Views/RCTScrollViewManager.m#L131-L146) or the [android implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/82b0df9d2a6163879647691235f01b3067c471b8/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/scroll/ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager.java#L79-L88). This would be the points where one would have to implement the scroll speed.

Comment: Yes, i also saw the code . but there nothing is mentioned about the duration or anything where speed can be altered. waiting for that to come up in releases.

Comment: Hey, I just added a ProductPain entry for this feature: https://productpains.com/post/react-native/add-speed-attribute-to-scrollto

Comment: Thanks much .. :+1: 
will see into it more deeper and if could figure it out , will update here

Comment: @DanielSchmidt do you know if this is now possible, either with `FlatList` or possibly `ScrollView` components?

Comment: @PatNeedham Haven't looked into it in a while. You should check out the source, the docs are outdated at times :/

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty neat solution that uses the scrollview's content height to scroll an entire view (on mount). However, the same trick can be used (add a listener to an animated value) to create a scroll function that can be triggered by some event at any given moment (to any given value).

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Animated, Easing, ScrollView } from 'react-native'

const SlowAutoScroller = ({ children }) => {
  const scrollRef = useRef()
  const scrollAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0))
  const [contentHeight, setContentHeight] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollAnimation.current.addListener((animation) => {
      scrollRef.current &&
        scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
          y: animation.value,
          animated: false,
        })
    })

    if (contentHeight) {
      Animated.timing(scrollAnimation.current, {
        toValue: contentHeight,
        duration: contentHeight * 100,
        useNativeDriver: true,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      }).start()
    }
    return () => scrollAnimation.current.removeAllListeners()
  }, [contentHeight])

  return (
    <Animated.ScrollView
      ref={scrollRef}
      onContentSizeChange={(width, height) => {
        setContentHeight(height)
      }}
      onScrollBeginDrag={() => scrollAnimation.current.stopAnimation()}
    >
      {children}
    </Animated.ScrollView>
  )
}
```