# React Native - set content position instantly, avoid slow scroll

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native, scrollview

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035648/how-to-alter-scrollview-scrollto-scrolling-speed) points out that you can't control scroll speed when using `scrollTo` on a ScrollView. Is there an alternative to `scrollTo`, that just sets the content to the new position instantly (without any animation)?

That may be covered by the "you can't do it" answer I linked to, but wasn't sure because I don't know if setting the content to the new position instantly counted as scrolling or not.

I'm using a ListView, but since that is built with a ScrollView, I assume the same question applies to both.

Comment: Do you mean without animation? `animated` flag should do the work then - `.scrollTo({ y: 1000, animated: false })`, but in case with ListViews, content in that part you want to scroll to might not be loaded yet.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Hmm I did try `animated: false`, but it still scrolls smoothly and same speed.

Comment: Ah, I have a lead. I wonder if it's because the items in the list don't all load instantly, so it's not scrolling gradually, it's just adding list items gradually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206257/react-native-set-content-position-instantly-avoid-slow-scroll#comment69612257_41206257) mentioned, there is an `animated` flag you can set to `false`, to avoid the scroll animation. I had this, but thought it didn't work.

Turns out the scroll was only slow because the items in the ListView were being loaded gradually, so even instant scroll every time one was added still looked like gradual scroll.

To solve, I set the ListView's `pageSize` to 30 (the number of messages in the list) to encompass loading all the ListView's items in a single event loop, and thus get a single scroll jump, instead of a gradual scroll.

```
<ListView dataSource={messagesDataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderMessage}
          pageSize={DEFAULT_NUM_MESSAGES} />
```